# Right click Event handling for select open in new tab

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

It loads the same page when I right click and select open in new tab

Here is my hyperlink and I cant provide URL in href="" Because I am using this code for multiple pages.

```
<td style="color='@row.RowFontColor'">
<a class="openTarget" href="#open" id="TestDemoClick">
 @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Area) || row.Area.ToUpper().Equals("A1"))
   {
     <span class="fa fa-circle fa-1 link"></span>
   }

</a></td>
```

Here is the code for click.

```
$('body').on('click', '.openTarget', function () {
                $(this).parent().parent().dblclick();
            });
```

But the problem is when I right click on hyperlink and select open in new tab it loads the same page.

I want it should open the page insider. i.e. When I click on hyperlink and the page it loads I want that page also load when I right clicking and selects open in new tab.

Comment: what has this code to do with Model–View–Controller pattern ?

Comment: This code is in view

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the default click event

```
$('body').on('click', '.openTarget', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   $(this).parent().parent().dblclick();
});
```

Comment: No. It is disabling my click event. and nothing happens when I single click on it.

Comment: ok what exactly do you want your code to do,why are you triggering dblclick  on the parents parent ?

Comment: When I click on that hyperlink Actually on parent().parent selects my entire row. and double click enables me to enter in the page.

Comment: @Vinci then that means your code works correctly , you trigger dblclick so page refresh when you click on openTarget

Comment: Actually my code works correctly on click. But I want to work it when I right click on hyperlink and select open in new tab option. Then at that time it is loading me the same page. i.e. not working

Comment: when you select one in new tab the you  will open the url assigned to link so you will open the same page except you will add a has to the url `#open`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
$('.openTarget').on('click',function (e) {
                $(this).parent().parent().dblclick();
            });
```

If neccssary prevent the default click by using , e.preventDefault()

Comment: Actually my code works correctly on click. But I want to work it when I right click on hyperlink and select open in new tab option. Then at that time it is loading me the same page. i.e. not working

Answer (score 0):

Browser's contextmenu is like a alert box it's outside your control and you cannot modify what its menu link would refer to once it's been shown but there is  [`oncontextmenu`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oncontextmenu.asp) event that **gets fired after right-click but before menu is shown** so you still have some time to change href on `.openTarget` that would get pickedup by context menu when it appears.Assuming you aren't nesting anchors this should work fine :)

```
       $('body').on('contextmenu', '.openTarget', function () {
             var link = "something" // get link for this say 
            $(this).attr("href",link);
        });
```

Sample : https://jsfiddle.net/nj1ujLrb/